# Modern day version of Spinrite

Tags: data-recovery

I have been using [Spinrite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) for a long time to help fix errors on hard drives, recover files from dead drives, and refresh drives that were unusable before. But [Spinrite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) only work on drives up to 1TB (depending on cluster size). I am looking for some software that does the same sort of stuff as Spinrite does but on much larger drives (1+ TB).

(I have a drive that is 2TB and has started clicking and I want to recover the lost files, but [Spinrite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) errors out because it can't index the entire drive.)

Comment: Do you know that a new version is coming up? Steve temporarily stopped working on SR 6.1 to focus on SQRL (https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm), but he should be back on it (I'm lagging behind listening to Security Now, so I can't confirm 'is back')

Comment: @JanDoggen I knew he was working on the next version, but I'm guessing that it won't come out for another year or so and the drive I have won't last that long.

Comment: HDD Regenerator (http://www.dposoft.net/hdd.html, http://hddregenerator.net) claims to also "repair bad sectors (magnetic errors) on a hard disk surface" and "4K sector size support", but I don't know what disk sizes that translates too.

Comment: Would you mind adding some more details concerning your exact requirements etc? For someone not knowing *Spinrite*, you might be looking for a Solaris utility for a RAID system :) As a helper/guide, you might want to take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 4):

> I have a drive that is 2TB and has started clicking and I want to recover the lost files

Then you really should use data recovery programs, like [gddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) combined with partition/filesystem recovery programs or data carvers (testdisk/photorec).

SpinRite isn't made to just recover data from a worsening (clicking) drive, according to [Steve's video](https://www.grc.com/sr/whatitdoes.htm) it reads, flips bits, writes, reads, flips bits back & writes data again, that should "refresh" the data. It does read & move difficult to read/bad sectors, but it *writes them back onto the drive*, **not something you want to do with a failing drive**.

If your drive is clicking and probably about to fail completely or crash, you *really* want to copy the data onto a good drive **now**. After you have a backup, then maybe you can milk some more use out of the failing drive

Comment: I agree. Regarding this topic, here's a question that may be helpful: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7424/raw-copy-from-failed-hard-disk