# LiveUSB distro or BootCd or Recovery Disk for repairing NTFS partitions

Tags: repair, ntfs

I want to get away from Windows and switch to Linux, but Linux was unable to repair corrupted NTFS partitions.

I want a LiveUSB or BootCD or Recovery Disk which is capable of repairing NTFS partitions.

Some thing with Dos or multiOS boot CD with executables like CHkdisk etc.

I want the original partitions to be fixed and not data-recovery.

Comment: I have not tried it myself (and cannot, as I have no NTFS partitions to try with) – but [SystemRescueCd](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) is the best known tool in this context.

Comment: @Izzy What tool/cmd/cli-program does it use to repair NTFS partitions?

Comment: As I wrote: I don't have any NTFS partitions (I'm using Linux on all my machines, no MS stuff) – so I never checked for that. I just saw it recommended for all kind of "Windows repairs" without digging deeper. But according to [NTFS hard disk repair utility in linux](http://serverfault.com/q/191597/145213) it should be `ntfsfix` (from the Linux `ntfsprogs` suite).

Comment: @Izzy I need a non-Linux distro with MiniXP or DOS etc. `ntfsfix` is not working successfully with NTFS partitions on Linux. That is why I want a live distro.

Comment: Well, in that case you should remove the `linux-distro` tag from your question – as that marks "Linux" as a requirement for the software you're asking about :)

Comment: @Izzy I thought it was more of a suggestion. Removed the tag.

Comment: @Wally ah you do not want to do it in Linux anymore? Gosh, I think the answer I was going to write will not work then. :) BTW by "repair" you mean to extract and recover the data, right? You cannot "repair" heavily corrupted NTFS partitions *in place.*

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto No, just Chkdisk stuff. The stuff that Right Clicking on a Partition in Windows can do.

Comment: `chkdsk` is pretty basic and it's quite far from [NTFS reconstruction for corrupted partitions](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/31377/19806).