# Program to bulk handle files with invalid filenames in Windows

Tags: windows-7, file-management, data-recovery, file-format, filenames

I used [Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover the data from an external HDD that had been partially formatted for a minute or so. The data recovery was successful, but also included over 1000 files that had been truncated of their extensions and ended in nothing but a `.`. This made these files invalid to Windows, and therefore invisible to it - any attempt to handle them natively results in a "File Does Not Exist" error.

I'm aware that I can use the Windows API path syntax (`//?/`) to bypass the default filename limitations and handle the files via the command line, but I need to move, rename and delete all of these files several times over, so I need either a GUI or CLI specifically designed for the task.

**Is there a program out there that will allow me to do this?**

Comment: Having no extension or an extension of . should not result in invalid file in windows __can__ you access the files with the `//?/` syntax?

Comment: Cross-site related: https://superuser.com/questions/214684/renaming-an-invalid-filename-in-ntfs

Comment: Was the drive NTFS? If yes, you might want to use RecuperaBit to recover the original file names: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/31377/19806 (disclaimer: I am the developer)